# Query Has The Wrong Type

Tags: java, sql, jooq

jOOQ 3.10.7 chooses the wrong type (`bigint` instead of `boolean`) in a multi-row upsert if the `boolean` is `null` in the first row.

Below is the general code to build and execute the query.

```java
try (Connection writeConn = DatabaseManager.getConnection(true);
        final DSLContext writeContext = DatabaseManager.getBuilder(writeConn);
        InsertQuery<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> programAssignmentsUpdateQuery = writeContext
                .insertQuery(AccessControlWriteDAO.userProgramAssignments)) {
            programAssignments
                    .forEach(assignment -> programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.addRecord(assignment));
            programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.addValuesForUpdate(UserProgramAssignment.getExcludedMap());
            programAssignmentsUpdateQuery
                    .addConditions(UserProgramAssignment.getUpsertUpdateCondition());
            programAssignmentsUpdateQuery.execute();
        }
}
```

The generated query (with the data inlined) is:

```sql
insert into "user_program_assignments" (
  "program_id",
  "create_projects",
  "justification",
  "modified_by",
  "modified_date",
  "user_id",
  "approve_all_child_projects",
  "edit_all_draft_child_projects",
  "moderate_all_child_projects",
  "view_all_draft_child_projects",
  "administer"
)
values (
  18792,
  true,
  'Permissions Moderator access added per xxx.',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  469882,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  null
), (
  18792,
  true,
  'Adding additional authority for this program/project',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  78116,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  null
), (
  18792,
  false,
  'Resetting for new programs/projects',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  97395,
  false,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  null
), (
  18792,
  true,
  'Updating to new program/project structure',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  135253,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true
), (
  18792,
  true,
  'Will be assisting with ARMD data entry.',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  296287,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  null
), (
  18792,
  true,
  'Resetting for new programs/projects',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  111237,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  true,
  null
), (
  18792,
  true,
  'TEST',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  237927,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  null
), (
  18792,
  true,
  'TEST',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  520822,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  null
), (
  18792,
  true,
  'TEST',
  '24',
  timestamp '2018-06-22 08:19:44.977',
  554733,
  true,
  true,
  false,
  true,
  true
)
on conflict (
  "program_id",
  "user_id"
) do update
set "approve_all_child_projects" = "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects",
    "create_projects" = "excluded"."create_projects",
    "edit_all_draft_child_projects" = "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects",
    "view_all_draft_child_projects" = "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects",
    "modified_by" = "excluded"."modified_by",
    "administer" = "excluded"."administer",
    "justification" = "excluded"."justification",
    "moderate_all_child_projects" = "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects",
    "modified_date" = "excluded"."modified_date"
where (
  "user_program_assignments"."approve_all_child_projects" <> "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."approve_all_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."approve_all_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."create_projects" <> "excluded"."create_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."create_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."create_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."create_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."create_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" <> "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."moderate_all_child_projects" <> "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."moderate_all_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."moderate_all_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."view_all_draft_child_projects" <> "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."justification" <> "excluded"."justification"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."justification" is null
    and "excluded"."justification" is not null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."administer" <> "excluded"."administer"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."administer" is null
    and "excluded"."administer" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."administer" is not null
    and "excluded"."administer" is null
  )
);
```

The query (with the data not inlined) is:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into "user_program_assignments" (
  "program_id", 
  "create_projects", 
  "justification", 
  "modified_by", 
  "modified_date", 
  "user_id", 
  "approve_all_child_projects", 
  "edit_all_draft_child_projects", 
  "moderate_all_child_projects", 
  "view_all_draft_child_projects", 
  "administer"
)
values (
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  cast(? as timestamp), 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?
), (
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  cast(? as timestamp), 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?
), (
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  cast(? as timestamp), 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?
), (
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  cast(? as timestamp), 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?
), (
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  cast(? as timestamp), 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?
), (
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  cast(? as timestamp), 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?
), (
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  cast(? as timestamp), 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?, 
  ?
)
on conflict (
  "program_id", 
  "user_id"
) do update
set "approve_all_child_projects" = "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects", 
    "create_projects" = "excluded"."create_projects", 
    "edit_all_draft_child_projects" = "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects", 
    "view_all_draft_child_projects" = "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects", 
    "modified_by" = "excluded"."modified_by", 
    "administer" = "excluded"."administer", 
    "justification" = "excluded"."justification", 
    "moderate_all_child_projects" = "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects", 
    "modified_date" = "excluded"."modified_date"
where (
  "user_program_assignments"."approve_all_child_projects" <> "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."approve_all_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."approve_all_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."approve_all_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."create_projects" <> "excluded"."create_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."create_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."create_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."create_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."create_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" <> "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."edit_all_draft_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."moderate_all_child_projects" <> "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."moderate_all_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."moderate_all_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."moderate_all_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."view_all_draft_child_projects" <> "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is null
    and "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is not null
    and "excluded"."view_all_draft_child_projects" is null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."justification" <> "excluded"."justification"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."justification" is null
    and "excluded"."justification" is not null
  )
  or "user_program_assignments"."administer" <> "excluded"."administer"
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."administer" is null
    and "excluded"."administer" is not null
  )
  or (
    "user_program_assignments"."administer" is not null
    and "excluded"."administer" is null
  )
)]; ERROR: column "administer" is of type boolean but expression is of type bigint
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 861
    at org.jooq_3.10.7.POSTGRES_9_5.debug(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2241) ~[jooq-3.10.7.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:704) ~[jooq-3.10.7.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:361) ~[jooq-3.10.7.jar:?]
    at xxx.upsertCapabilities(xxx:467) ~[classes/:?]
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "administer" is of type boolean but expression is of type bigint
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 861
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2178) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:144) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44) ~[HikariCP-2.6.3.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.6.3.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209) ~[jooq-3.10.7.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:429) ~[jooq-3.10.7.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractDMLQuery.execute(AbstractDMLQuery.java:452) ~[jooq-3.10.7.jar:?]
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:347) ~[jooq-3.10.7.jar:?]
    ... 124 more
```

The DDL of the table is:

```
create table user_program_assignments
(
    program_id bigint not null
        constraint pgua_pg___fk
            references programs
                on delete cascade,
    create_projects boolean,
    justification varchar(4000),
    modified_by varchar(30) not null,
    modified_date timestamp default timezone('UTC'::text, now()) not null,
    user_id bigint not null
        constraint pgua_ui___fk
            references users
                on delete cascade,
    administer boolean default false not null,
    approve_all_child_projects boolean default false not null,
    edit_all_draft_child_projects boolean default false not null,
    moderate_all_child_projects boolean default false not null,
    view_all_draft_child_projects boolean default false not null,
    constraint user_program_assignments_pkey
        primary key (program_id, user_id)
)
;
```

The file generated by jOOQ is (please note that 3.11.1's file is the same and 3.11.1 worked *using* this file):

```
/*
 * This file is generated by jOOQ.
*/
...
/**
 * Table to store user permissions for a given program.
 */
@Generated(
    value = {
        "http://www.jooq.org",
        "jOOQ version:3.10.7"
    },
    comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ"
)
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public class UserProgramAssignments extends TableImpl<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1670872896;

    /**
     * The reference instance of <code>user_program_assignments</code>
     */
    public static final UserProgramAssignments USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS = new UserProgramAssignments();

    /**
     * The class holding records for this type
     */
    @Override
    public Class<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> getRecordType() {
        return UserProgramAssignmentsRecord.class;
    }

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.program_id</code>. Foreign key reference to the Programs table. Combines with the user_id column to create the primary key.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Long> PROGRAM_ID = createField("program_id", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BIGINT.nullable(false), this, "Foreign key reference to the Programs table. Combines with the user_id column to create the primary key.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.create_projects</code>. If true, the user is able to create projects under the specified program.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Boolean> CREATE_PROJECTS = createField("create_projects", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN, this, "If true, the user is able to create projects under the specified program.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.justification</code>. The rationale for the user's level of permission assignments on the program.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, String> JUSTIFICATION = createField("justification", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARCHAR(4000), this, "The rationale for the user's level of permission assignments on the program.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.modified_by</code>. Standard column used to identify the person who created/modified the record.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, String> MODIFIED_BY = createField("modified_by", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.VARCHAR(30).nullable(false), this, "Standard column used to identify the person who created/modified the record.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.modified_date</code>. Standard column used to identify the when the record was created/last modified and should be tied to the modified_by field.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, LocalDateTime> MODIFIED_DATE = createField("modified_date", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("timezone('UTC'::text, now())", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME)), this, "Standard column used to identify the when the record was created/last modified and should be tied to the modified_by field.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.user_id</code>. Foreign key reference to the Users table. Combines with the program_id column to create the primary key.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Long> USER_ID = createField("user_id", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BIGINT.nullable(false), this, "Foreign key reference to the Users table. Combines with the program_id column to create the primary key.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.administer</code>. If true, the user is able to moderate, edit, and otherwise administer the specified program.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Boolean> ADMINISTER = createField("administer", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("false", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN)), this, "If true, the user is able to moderate, edit, and otherwise administer the specified program.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.approve_all_child_projects</code>. 0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permissions for approving all draft projects under this program.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Boolean> APPROVE_ALL_CHILD_PROJECTS = createField("approve_all_child_projects", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("false", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN)), this, "0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permissions for approving all draft projects under this program.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.edit_all_draft_child_projects</code>. 0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permissions for editing all draft projects under this program.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Boolean> EDIT_ALL_DRAFT_CHILD_PROJECTS = createField("edit_all_draft_child_projects", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("false", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN)), this, "0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permissions for editing all draft projects under this program.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.moderate_all_child_projects</code>. 0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permission to set user permissions on all projects under this program.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Boolean> MODERATE_ALL_CHILD_PROJECTS = createField("moderate_all_child_projects", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("false", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN)), this, "0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permission to set user permissions on all projects under this program.");

    /**
     * The column <code>user_program_assignments.view_all_draft_child_projects</code>. 0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permissions for viewing all draft projects under this program.
     */
    public final TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, Boolean> VIEW_ALL_DRAFT_CHILD_PROJECTS = createField("view_all_draft_child_projects", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN.nullable(false).defaultValue(org.jooq.impl.DSL.field("false", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.BOOLEAN)), this, "0/1 toggle flag identifying whether or not the user has permissions for viewing all draft projects under this program.");

    /**
     * Create a <code>user_program_assignments</code> table reference
     */
    public UserProgramAssignments() {
        this(DSL.name("user_program_assignments"), null);
    }

    /**
     * Create an aliased <code>user_program_assignments</code> table reference
     */
    public UserProgramAssignments(String alias) {
        this(DSL.name(alias), USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS);
    }

    /**
     * Create an aliased <code>user_program_assignments</code> table reference
     */
    public UserProgramAssignments(Name alias) {
        this(alias, USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS);
    }

    private UserProgramAssignments(Name alias, Table<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> aliased) {
        this(alias, aliased, null);
    }

    private UserProgramAssignments(Name alias, Table<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> aliased, Field<?>[] parameters) {
        super(alias, null, aliased, parameters, "Table to store user permissions for a given program.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<Index> getIndexes() {
        return Arrays.<Index>asList(Indexes.PGUA_UIPI___INDEX, Indexes.USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS_PKEY);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public UniqueKey<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord> getPrimaryKey() {
        return Keys.USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS_PKEY;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<UniqueKey<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord>> getKeys() {
        return Arrays.<UniqueKey<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord>>asList(Keys.USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS_PKEY);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<ForeignKey<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, ?>> getReferences() {
        return Arrays.<ForeignKey<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, ?>>asList(Keys.USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS__PGUA_PG___FK, Keys.USER_PROGRAM_ASSIGNMENTS__PGUA_UI___FK);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public TableField<UserProgramAssignmentsRecord, LocalDateTime> getRecordTimestamp() {
        return MODIFIED_DATE;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public UserProgramAssignments as(String alias) {
        return new UserProgramAssignments(DSL.name(alias), this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public UserProgramAssignments as(Name alias) {
        return new UserProgramAssignments(alias, this);
    }

    /**
     * Rename this table
     */
    @Override
    public UserProgramAssignments rename(String name) {
        return new UserProgramAssignments(DSL.name(name), null);
    }

    /**
     * Rename this table
     */
    @Override
    public UserProgramAssignments rename(Name name) {
        return new UserProgramAssignments(name, null);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the DDL of the `user_program_assignments` table, and what does its generated code look like? Have you applied any converters / bindings to the `administer` column? Btw: would be great if you could reduce your question to an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No converters or bindings to the column.  I've edited the text.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Everything looks OK in your posted code, the type is mapped to `Boolean`, which it should. So, I'm afraid I'm not sure how to reproduce this...